# Container element types

Tags: haskell, types, containers

In a way this is a step backwards from my earlier question, but... Can somebody remind me why this *doesn't* work?

```
class Container c e where
  empty :: c
  insert :: e -> c -> c

instance Container [x] x where
  empty = []
  insert = (:)

instance Container ByteString Word8 where
  empty = BIN.empty
  insert = BIN.cons

instance Ord x => Container (Set x) x where
  empty = SET.empty
  insert = SET.insert
```

Obviously if it was that easy, nobody would have bothered to invent functional dependencies nor associated types. So what's the problem with the above?

Comment: Try using it.  You'll soon get complaints about ambiguous overloading.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing to stop you from adding `instance Container [Int] Int` and `instance Container [Int] Char`, and when you ask for `empty :: [Int]` the compiler has no way of knowing which instance it's supposed to come from.

"Ah, but I only have `instance Container [Int] Int`," you say. "And an `instance Container [Int] Char` would be a bug anyway."

But the compiler cannot know that you will not add an `instance Container [Int] Char` in the future, and if you do, it is not allowed for it to break your existing code.

So we need some way of telling the compiler that

- the first parameter of `Container` uniquely determines the second parameter of `Container`
- if it sees different instances that differ only in the second type, that indicates a bug

Enter functional dependencies.